# Insert into view not returning primary key

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I've mapped a POCO to a view. When EF does an insert, it generates the following command...

```
INSERT INTO "public"."vw_place"("Name","Description","Point") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "PlaceId"
```

But the code, throws the following error...

> {"A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member
>   'PlaceId' of type 'DataAccess.Place'."}

Here is the trigger function that does the insert...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vw_place_dml()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
                   BEGIN
                      IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN

                        INSERT INTO tbl_place
                        (
                        "Name",
                        "Description",
                        "Point"
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        NEW."Name",
                        NEW."Description",
                        ST_GeomFromWKB(NEW."Point", 4326)
                    );

                            RETURN NEW;

                            ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN

                          UPDATE tbl_place SET
                        "PlaceId" = NEW."PlaceId",
                        "Name" = NEW."Name",
                        "Description" = NEW."Description",
                        "Point" = ST_GeomFromWKB(NEW."Point", 4326)
                    WHERE
                        "PlaceId" = OLD."PlaceId";

                            RETURN NEW;

                            END IF;
                            RETURN NEW;
                            END;
                $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION vw_place_dml()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

If I run this in pgAdmin it returns nothing, which is the problem, but the row is successfully inserted and a PlaceId is generated.

```
INSERT INTO "public"."vw_place"("Name","Description","Point") VALUES
('ergw','regr','\x0101000000000000009846b2bfe4e068d7ff33a73f')

RETURNING "PlaceId"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the insert in the trigger function and before `RETURN NEW;`, I added...

```
NEW."PlaceId" = currval('"tbl_place_PlaceId_seq"');
```

Comment: Not sure if this is concurrency-safe. In Sql Server it isn't. Doens't Postgresql have an equivalent of SS's `Scope_Identity` function?

Comment: I think that's it. It says here regarding currval, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-sequence.html, "Notice that because this is returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether or not other sessions have executed nextval since the current session did."